# is there a workaround for sql server reporting servicesdate format (ddd)?

Tags: reporting-services

I'm using Sql Server 2016 Reporting Services, but Format String "ddd, dd.MM.yy" isn't displaying Weekday name, only 29.11.2018, bit should display Do,29.11.2018

any workaround / fix ?

ssrs ddd date format not working

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the format

`dddd, dd.MM.yyyy`

This will give you the full day name Wednesday though, not Wed or whatever your locale day names are.